# How to move the button inside the pictureBox1 without leave the pictureBox area?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width);
            int y = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Height);
            button1.Top = y;
            button1.Left = x;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

EDIT**

```
int x1 = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width);
            int y1 = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Height);
            randomPoint = new Point(x1, y1);
            if (currentPosition.X != randomPoint.X)
            {
                if (currentPosition.X > randomPoint.X)
                    currentPosition.X -= 1;
                else
                    currentPosition.X += 1;

                button1.Location = currentPosition;
            }
            else if (currentPosition.Y != randomPoint.Y)
            {
                if (currentPosition.Y > randomPoint.Y)
                    currentPosition.Y -= 1;
                else
                    currentPosition.Y += 1;

                button1.Location = currentPosition;
            }
            else
            {
                randomPoint.X = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width - button1.Width - 1);
                randomPoint.Y = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Height - button1.Height - 1);
            }
```

In top of the form i did:

```
int x ;
int y ;
Point currentPosition;
Point randomPoint;
```

In constructor:

x = button1.Location.X;
y = button1.Location.Y;
currentPosition = new Point(x, y);

Comment: You have to first get to the random point and then choose another one

Comment: valter edited my question with what i tried now. Can you show me how to do it right ?

Comment: It will take some work. I will see what i can do

Comment: If you want it to slide then `y` axis should not be change but `x` axis should change. And if you want it always to the right then it should be higher value than before. If to the left then lower value than before.

Comment: Edper but i want to use the random. So it will slide each time to a randon new point.

Comment: Edited my question now y is not moving. But im using the randon variable and its jumping each time randomaly to the new location. I could make it slide before but only to one direction. My first edit is sliding but only to the right. I want it to slide randomaly.

Comment: Also in my first edit its not realy slide its jumping each time by 1 and then i changed the timer to 10ms interval so it look like sliding. But i want it to slide randomaly.

Comment: Another thing. `Picturebox` must be the parent of button otherwise point `0,0` will be measured from form position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form load event do:

```
currentPosition = button1.Location;
randomPoint.X = r.Next(0, PictureBox1.Width - Button1.Width - 1);
randomPoint.Y = r.Next(0, PictureBox1.Height - Button1.Height - 1);
```

Inside your timer:

```
if(currentPosition.X != randomPoint.X){
    if (currentPosition.X > randomPoint.X)
        currentPosition.X -= 1;
    else
        currentPosition.X += 1;

    Button1.Location = currentPosition;
}
else if(currentPosition.Y != randomPoint.Y){
    if(currentPosition.Y > randomPoint.Y)
        currentPosition.Y -= 1;
    else
        currentPosition.Y += 1;

    Button1.Location = currentPosition;
}
else{
    randomPoint.X = r.Next(0, PictureBox1.Width - Button1.Width - 1);
    randomPoint.Y = r.Next(0, PictureBox1.Height - Button1.Height - 1);
}
```

As far as the movement, you can increase `picturebox` size `or(and)` dicrease `button` size.
Dont forget to declare `Random r = new Random();` where you declared `currentPosition` and `randomPoint`.

valter